# Trying to get the current month/year when user changes month view

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm using fullcalendar-scheduler and trying to get the current month and year whenever the user selects a new date view. For example, whenever the user selects a previous/next month, or week, or day, I need a trigger to update some things.

What I have is close, but it gives me the wrong month:

```
  datesSet: function(info) {
    var y = info.view.currentStart.getFullYear();
    var m = info.view.currentStart.getMonth();
    alert('year  = ' + y + ' month  = ' + m);
  }
```

It looks like dateSet is triggered when the date changes (which is good) but currentStart.getMonth seems to always give me a number that is not the current month. It is always giving me the current month minus one (I think).

Before I happily go adding 1 to the month it gives me, I'd like to know if I'm doing it wrong. Or, if I'm doing it correctly and the index is simply zero = January instead of 1 = January.

Comment: in the JS Date object, month numbers start at 0. This is universal, it's not specific to fullCalendar. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Comment: P.S. What exactly are you going to do once you've got this information? If you want to use it to update the list of events in the calendar, then this is not the correct approach.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that information. It did seem consistent and reliable, but I wanted to make sure. My calendar is showing the jobs and people scheduled to work each day. When a month is blank we start with X people-days available. As jobs are added the number of remaining people-days is reduced. So, at the top of the page, above the calendar, I'm showing the remaining available time (in people-days). This number is different for each month so I have to update it as the user navigates from one month to the next. It will be a big help in capacity planning.